# The origin of Gauss' law for magnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, gauss-law

What is the physical axiom leading us to the Gauss' law for magnetism?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of lack of research effort.

Comment: you had better give an answer if it doesn't seem ambiguous enough.

Answer (score 2):

The physical axiom leading us to Gauss' law is that magnetic monopoles (equivalent to electric charges) do not exist.

Comment: That's the consequence!

Comment: @NavidSanayei Nope, that is the experimental input.

Comment: @Navid: Or that's the observation and the mathematical statement confirms it.